# Google Maps - sometimes tiles not loading when dragging

Tags: javascript, google-maps

In general my Google Maps API V3 / Javascript application is working fine. I only have noticed one issue:

From time to time - I can not really tell when - the (new) tiles are not loaded when I drag the map. This is a bit disturbing. Since my application is used with the API V3, I do no longer use a Google Key. Closing the browser usually solves the issue.

Currently the application is in development with, so there should be no restriction due too much traffic from Google. I do not see any JavaScript issues in the console.

Any idea what this could be?

- Remarks added -
  My Internet connectivity seems to be OK when this happens, also I am at a proper zoom factor and in a "well defined area" where titles are available.

Comment: Are you getting a tile with a text "There is no imagery at this location"

Comment: To me this even happens with the "official" Google Maps frontend also from time to time.

Comment: I do not get any type of text or so, I am also at a proper zoom factor and in a known area where I should get tiles - I just get nothing.

Also I have noticed it with the offical map, but very rarely.

Comment: Guess it is specific to my scenario, and although I have not really found the root cause, I'll close it for now. If I'll find something substantial I'll reopen it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

well I have seen this issue is mostly with the internet connectivity on the client side. Please make sure that you are not being disconnected of the net when the requests are being sent. I would watch out for that..

you can monitor your connection with some tool like : http://www.connectionmonitor.net/

FYI I am not advertising the tool, first result from google search

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, but this is highly unlikely with my broadband ASDL. I'll watch this in particular next time, but I doubt it. At least I have not noticed a general coincidence.

Comment: well your internet connection might go down all of a sudden right.. it happens on all connections.. if the same image is returned by google on page refresh then i dnt think google is the culprit

Comment: Yep, I'll have an eye on this, will report here when it happens.

Comment: It is no network issue, at least not in the situations when I have crosschecked it. At the very same time it works in another browser, also the network monitor does not show any indications of a failure. Ironically most of the times this "hanging" happens with Google Chrome.

Comment: just look at the Net tab of the developer tools and see what happens to these requests.. are they even fired or they just die in between.. may be a memory issue of chrome.. also make sure you are on the stable build of google.. googles dev build is nasty

Comment: This is not a bad idea, to crosscheck the beta vs. the released Chrome version - if it is Chrome beta specific I might have found the root cause. Thanks for pointing this out.